# Extract date from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I'm using this code to extract date from text without time. Is there any method to extract date without time and vice versa?

```
$(document).on("change", "#select_date", function() {
  const at = $('#select_date :selected').text()
  //2016-03-26 15:22:02 
  const attend_date = at.substring(0,10)
});
```

Comment: You can use regexes.

Comment: split() easier to use .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `split()` the date by space and select the first part:

```
$(document).on("change", "#select_date", function() {
  const at = $('#select_date :selected').text()
  const attend_date = at.split(' ')[0]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("change", "#select_date", function() {
  const at = $('#select_date :selected').text()

  //extract date
  const attend_date = at.split(' ')[0]
  //extract time
  const attend_time = at.split(' ')[1]
})
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation to your solution. Code only answers are frowned upon.